# How to prevent blender blocking computer entering stand by state?

Tags: rendering, windows

I often leave my Windows computer on overnight, and sometimes I have Blender running when I do so.  I've noticed that when Blender is running that my computer will not enter it's powered down state.  While I can understand how this would be useful for rendering, I'm not doing any rendering and would prefer that my computer go into low power consumption when I'm not using it.

Is there any way to stop Blender from preventing my computer from going into stand by mode?